# Exception: No Linux desktop project configured error on flutter project

Tags: linux, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-desktop

When I try to build my app to Flutter Desktop its fail with this message:

```
Running "flutter pub get" in project...
    Launching lib/main.dart on Linux in debug mode...
    Exception: No Linux desktop project configured. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Desktop-shells#create to learn about adding Linux support to a project.
```

My configuration is:

```
flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel master, 1.20.0-3.0.pre.126, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: What is your question? You haven't said what issue you encountered while following the instructions for setting up your project.

Comment: when I'm run a command 'flutter run -d linux' compiler show this error

Comment: following the instructions for setting up for the project has been already done!

Comment: You should update your question with the output of `ls linux` in your project's root directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might have missed step from linux desktop support. It is because you're trying to run project which is initial build from different platform (eg. mac/windows).  This is according to official documentation.
[flutter_add_linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eQKK.png)

Another solution is create new app by `flutter create repo_name` on linux. Then copy linux folder into existing repo. This will fix your problem.

Answer (score 46):

you have to manually add desktop support for existing apps

run: `flutter create .`
to add the necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

To add desktop support to an existing Flutter project, run the following command in a terminal from the root project directory:

```
flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux .
```

src : https://flutter.dev/desktop#add-desktop-support-to-an-existing-flutter-app

Comment: just for who get error after running this command, need to include ``--org`` parameter if you changed the package name.

Comment: Do not miss the dot in the end of the expression

Answer (score 3):

**While run desktop app *error***
[image]

### **solution:**

To add desktop support to an existing Flutter project, run the following command in a terminal from the root project directory:

[image]

Here we add **full desktop** support

```
flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux .
```

Only need **Windows**

```
flutter create --platforms=windows .
```

Only need **Linux**

```
flutter create --platforms=linux .
```

### Tip:

To create a new application that includes desktop support (in addition to mobile and web support), run the following commands, substituting myapp with the name of your project:

```
flutter create myapp
cd myapp
```

For more Information : [flutter.dev/desktop](https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop)

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands

`$ flutter channel dev`

`$ flutter upgrade`

`$ flutter config --enable-linux-desktop`

After running these commands start a new Flutter project and you should be good to go. :)

Answer (score 0):

First run the following command

**flutter create --platforms=windows,macos,linux .**

and then run any of the following according to need.

**flutter build windows**

**flutter build macos**

**flutter build linux**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).